# Raycasting is slower than expected

Tags: unity-game-engine, optimization, raycasting

I'm profiling my game through the built in Unity Profiler on my phone using Unity Remote 5 to control the game. This introduces overhead but as I understand that still shouldn't affect the performance of something like Raycasting.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz6ZH.jpg

Is this kind of performance expected? I feel like it shouldn't take 21ms to complete 8 raycasts but how would I know

Comment: 21ms seems high, but we have no reference to how many and how often `Physics.Raycast2D` is being called. Could you provide your code? Check https://answers.unity.com/questions/369519/raycast-performance.html for some performance numbers regarding raycasting

Comment: @Eliasar I did a build and run for no real reason and after it obviously not showing up on Unity Remote I closed it, hit play in the editor and profiled my game as per usual. Same as the last time I profiled, 8 raycasts were performed bit now it took less the 1ms to complete. I have no idea why, do I delete my question at this point or what?

Comment: Either that or close it for typographical or non-reproducible